# I am trying to import my database values, but the results are not being displayed, even though the table structure is correct

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

Table creation here at views.py

```
def products(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
                return redirect('show')
            except:
                pass
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
    return render(request,'show.html',{'form':form})
```

This is the content from show.html file.

```
<tbody>  
    {% for items in products %} 
    <tr>  
        <td>{{ items.pid }}</td>  
        <td>{{ items.pname }}</td>  
        <td>{{ items.pprice }}</td>  
        <td>  
            <a href="/edit/{{ items.id }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" >Edit</span></a>  
            <a href="/delete/{{ items.id }}">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Delete</span></a>  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
    {% endfor %}  

    </tbody>
```

The database value isn't being displayed on the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only context you pass to the `show.html` template is `form`.

In your template you use `products` and because this variable does not exist you aren't getting any output.